# Where does the '48' come from in the byte string b'\xbb\x010'?

Tags: python, byte

I am attempting to interpret a byte string and I'm not sure what I'm missing when evaluating:

```
byte_string = b'\xbb\x010'
```

I understand, in python, that `\x` denotes a hexadecimal for the next two characters in the string. So, I get that:

```
\xbb = byte_string[0] = 187(decimal)

\x01 = byte_string[1] = 1(decimal)
```

However, I am unclear why:

```
byte_string[2] = 48(decimal)
```

Where did the `48` come from? What is `byte_string[2]` referencing?

Comment: Separated into bytes `b'\xbb' + b'\x01' + b'0'`, you have a third byte written as ascii https://www.ascii-code.com/

Comment: The third character is the `0`. `ord('0')` is `48`.